# Create my own local and remote branch and pull from a remote branch only once

Tags: git, github, version-control

So in our repository we currently have the following branches:

```
Master
Dev1
```

I would like to create my own local and remote branch called Dev2 and would like it to initially pull from the remote Dev1 instead of Master (since Dev1 is the most up-to-date and hasn't merged into the Master branch yet). When I then push to my remote branch I want to be pushin to Dev2 which should be a completely detached and independent branch from Dev1.

How could I do this? I am new to using Git, if you couldn't tell :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first fetch the remote branch on your local system by

> git fetch remote_name remote_branch_name

in your case the remote_branch_name would be Dev1

Now you need to create a new branch from Dev1, which you can do like this

> git checkout -b new_branch_name remote_name/remote_branch_name

new_branch_name for you would be Dev2

Now whenever you'll push, you can do

> git push remote_name new_branch_name

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands to meet your requirement:

```
git checkout origin/Dev1
git checkout --orphan Dev2
# make some changes and commit them if have
git push -u origin Dev2
```